# cron_last vs node_cron_last variable

Tags: 7, cron

I wanted to get the **time** of last node update (any node). So, then I thought I could simple pick **last cron run time** ( because I am using feeds module to pull the RSS feeds so nodes will be updated on every cron run ). but then I discovered another variable "node_cron_last".

Can anyone explain me the difference between two variables, what value they contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only place `node_cron_last` is set is in [`_node_index_node()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/_node_index_node/7), which is run when indexing a node for search results.

Its purpose, per the comments:

> Save the changed time of the most recent indexed node, for the search results half-life calculation.

`cron_last` is simply used to

> Record cron time.

per [`drupal_cron_run()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_cron_run/7)

Given that `REQUEST_TIME` is used for all values (cron variables + node changed date) in the same request, you might well expect those two variables to contain the same value.

Comment: I did some trails, it seems like those two contains different values. running Corn updates value of "cron_last" but not "node_cron_last". But it seems like for the node update the "node_cron_last" is getting updated. Thanks you.

Comment: Pretty sure `node_cron_last` will only get updated if there are nodes to be indexed.

Comment: @MPD Definitely; but given the update hook in the search module ([`search_node_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.module/function/search_node_update/7)) I would've thought nodes being updated in the same job would be re-indexed

Comment: @MPD Nope, you're right - the update hooks just queues it for re-indexing, doesn't guarantee it will be in the same job

Comment: @Clive  I am running a news site (pulling rss feeds using feeds module), I wanted to get the time last time the nodes were updated , which variable should be used in this context?